# Postfix, Courier, and backups - appropriate file permissions?

Tags: email, postfix, imap, courier

Picture a mail store for virtual users. Arriving mail is managed by Postfix (creating new files); access to mail is provided by Courier IMAP (moving files around, deleting files, creating sent mail); and periodically, off-site backups are taken (reading files without changing anything). Obviously this will all work if every process runs as root; equally obviously, they shouldn't all run as root.

The current setup has all the files owned by the `postfix` user and group. The Postfix and Courier processes all run as that uid/gid. But I would like to have the backup process run as a dedicated read-only user.

Is there a way to tell Postfix and Courier to create their files as user backup:postfix with permissions 0464/0575? I'm on Debian GNU/Linux if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I've come to the conclusion that this isn't possible; it's a form of file giveaway (because the `postfix` user would need to create files owned by `backup`). Looks like the backup program will simply have to run with group access to the mailstore, and thus be depended on to not change anything.